# Exception while cosuming/ completing msg using python-sdk from Azure service bus queue

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-python-sdk

There are around 2M messages in azure service bus queue. I am trying consume 10k msgs as a batch using below code. After consuming around 8L messages surprisingly got exception like Unable to retrieve last received message number.

Below is the sample code

```
def consume_messages_from_queue(service_bus_queue: ServiceBusQueue) -> list[dict]:
    """
    return at max 10000 consumed msgs from service bus queue with max wait time as 15 seconds
    """
    with ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=service_bus_queue.conn_str, transport_type=TransportType.AmqpOverWebsocket) as servicebus_client:
        with servicebus_client.get_queue_receiver(queue_name=service_bus_queue.queue_name) as receiver:
            received_msgs = receiver.receive_messages(
                max_message_count=10000, max_wait_time=15)
            received_msgs_json = []
            for msg in received_msgs:
                try:
                    received_msgs_json.append(json.loads(str(msg)))
                    receiver.complete_message(msg)
                except Exception as ex:
                    print(
                        f'Exception in converting service bus message to json: {ex}')
                    receiver.dead_letter_message(message=msg, reason=str(ex))
            return received_msgs_json
```

Below is the Exception stack trace

```
File ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uamqp/receiver.py:229, in MessageReceiver._message_received(self, message)
    221 """Callback run on receipt of every message. If there is
    222 a user-defined callback, this will be called.
    223 Additionally if the client is retrieving messages for a batch
   (...)
    226 :param message: c_uamqp.Message
    227 """
    228 # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 229 message_number = self._receiver.last_received_message_number()
    230 if self._settle_mode == constants.ReceiverSettleMode.ReceiveAndDelete:
    231     settler = None

File ./src/message_receiver.pyx:67, in uamqp.c_uamqp.cMessageReceiver.last_received_message_number()

File ./src/message_receiver.pyx:70, in uamqp.c_uamqp.cMessageReceiver.last_received_message_number()

File ./src/base.pyx:31, in uamqp.c_uamqp.StructBase._value_error()

ValueError: Operation failed.
Error: Unable to retrieve last received message number.
```

Comment: It happens for various reasons, including network issues or problems with the Azure Service Bus service.

Comment: This looks to be an older version of the Python library.  The stack trace indicates that this is a state issue in the uamqp library, which we do not recommend.  I'd strongly suggest updating to the latest package, which uses a new AMQP stack that would be more stable.

Answer (score 0):

The exception `Unable to retrieve last received message number` can happen for various reasons, including network issues or problems with the Azure Service Bus service. It can also happen if you are using an older version of the Python SDK.Thank for the point about older version @Jesse Squire.

I have tried a similar code to receive messages from an Azure service bus [queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-python-how-to-use-queues?tabs=passwordless#receive-messages-from-a-queue) and it worked.

- The code below consumes messages from an Azure Service Bus queue using the `azure.servicebus` library and is set up to receive and process messages from an Azure Service Bus queue.

```py
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, TransportType
from retry import retry

service_bus_conn_str = " "
queue_name = " "
def consume_messages_from_queue(service_bus_conn_str, queue_name):
  
    with ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=service_bus_conn_str, transport_type=TransportType.AmqpOverWebsocket) as servicebus_client:
        with servicebus_client.get_queue_receiver(queue_name=queue_name) as receiver:
            # Wrap the receive_messages call with a retry decorator
            @retry(tries=3, delay=5)
            def receive_messages_with_retry(receiver):
                return receiver.receive_messages(max_message_count=10000, max_wait_time=15)

            try:
                # Call the receive_messages_with_retry function
                received_msgs = receive_messages_with_retry(receiver)
                for msg in received_msgs:
                    message_content_type = msg.content_type
                    message_body = str(msg)

                    if not message_content_type:
                        # Treat messages without a content type as plain text
                        print(f"Received plain text message: {message_body}")
                    elif message_content_type == "text/plain":
                        print(f"Received plain text message: {message_body}")
                    elif message_content_type == "application/xml":
                        print(f"Received XML message: {message_body}")
                    elif message_content_type == "application/json":
                        print(f"Received JSON message: {message_body}")
                    else:
                        print(f"Received message with unknown content type: {message_content_type}")

                    receiver.complete_message(msg)

            except Exception as ex:
                print(f'Exception while receiving messages: {ex}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    consume_messages_from_queue(service_bus_conn_str, queue_name)
```

**Output:**

[image]